# Como Llenar un ListView con un ArrayAdapter en un Fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment, fragment

estoy probando un ejemplo de como leer ficheros xml remotos, y después de probar que funciona correctamente lo he modificado para integrarlo en un fragment de un Drawer Layout, con la decepción de que parece ser que no funciona igual a la hora de llenar un ListView con un ArrayAdapter dentro de un Main_Activity que en un fragment, he pegado el trozo de código y he marcado con un comentario las dos líneas que me dan el error.

espero haberme explicado bien,saludos.

Te dejo la el fragment completo, dentro está la función donde recojo todos los datos del XML, pero creo que el problema no va por ahi, el ArrayAdapter adaptador se crea y se llega a llenar bien con el string titulares

esta es la línea de código original utilizado en un MainActivity y que en el fragment me da error

```
ArrayAdapter adaptador  = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,titulares);
```

La he tenido que cambiar por esta otra que si me funciona

```
ArrayAdapter adaptador  = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,titulares);
```

El error me lo da cuando intento llenar el ListView listadoTitulos con el contendo del ArrayAdapter adaptador

```
listadoTitulos.setAdapter(adaptador);
```

Aquí tienes el fragment completo:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import static android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N;


public class NewsFragment extends Fragment implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

private URL url;
private ArrayList<ElCurso> UnCurso;
private String[] titulares;
private ListView listadoTitulos;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy permiso = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(permiso);

    listadoTitulos = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.vtTitulares);
    UnCurso = new ArrayList<ElCurso>();

    try {

        url = new URL(" http://www.videotutoriales.es/android-xml/cursos.xml")             
        leerxml();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        ArrayAdapter adaptador  = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,titulares);
        listadoTitulos.setAdapter(adaptador);
    listadoTitulos.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent (getActivity(),Detalle_curso.class);
            intent.putExtra("CURSO", UnCurso.get(position));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news, container, false);
}



    private void leerxml() {
    XmlPullParserFactory factory;
    XmlPullParser xml;

    int evento;



    boolean titulo;
    boolean imagen;
    boolean detalle;

    ArrayList<String> titulos;
    ArrayList<String> imagenes;
    ArrayList<String> detalles;

    titulo = false;
    imagen = false;
    detalle = false;

    titulos = new ArrayList<String>();
    imagenes = new ArrayList<String>();
    detalles = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        xml=factory.newPullParser();
        xml.setInput(url.openStream(), "UTF-8");

        evento=xml.getEventType();

        while (evento != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){

            switch (evento){
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    if (xml.getName().equals("titulo")){
                        titulo = true;
                    }
                    if (xml.getName().equals("imagen")){
                        imagen = true;
                    }
                    if (xml.getName().equals("detalle")){
                        detalle = true;
                    }
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                    if (titulo){
                        titulos.add(xml.getText());
                    }
                    if (imagen){
                        imagenes.add(xml.getText());
                    }
                    if (detalle){
                        detalles.add(xml.getText());
                    }
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    if (xml.getName().equals("titulo")){
                        titulo = false;
                    }
                    if (xml.getName().equals("imagen")){
                        imagen = false;
                    }
                    if (xml.getName().equals("detalle")){
                        detalle = false;
                    }
                    break;

            }
            evento = xml.next();
        }

        titulares = new String[titulos.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < titulos.size(); i++){
            UnCurso.add(new ElCurso(titulos.get(i), detalles.get(i), imagenes.get(i) ) );
            titulares[i] = titulos.get(i);
        }

    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

 @Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
    return false;
}
```

}

Y aquí el error que me da:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.corporation.toneti.toneti100, PID: 23983
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)'
>   on a null object reference
>           at com.corporation.toneti.toneti100.NewsFragment.onCreateView(NewsFragment.java:75)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2426)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1795)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1863)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2634)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2421)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2376)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2283)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3286)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3238)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:201)

Comment: Todo parece normal. Revisa de que en el `axml` el `ListView` tenga un tamaño diferente a cero o la visibilidad diferente de `gone`. Ademas, no veo donde se esta llenando la lista `titulares`. Asegúrate de que realmente la lista tenga resultados. Otra cosa, dices que te da error, pero no especifica cuales errores, la app se detiene o algo asi?.

Comment: Hola  Andrespengineer, he editado añadiendo la información que requerías, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estas buscando la referencia, en un espacio no existente en el `Fragment`. Debes asegurarte que cada referencia pertenezca al layout inflado por el `Fragment`.

Por ejemplo, en un `Activity` haces `setContentView` para setear el layout que cargara. Sin embargo en un `Fragment` es diferente. El `root` es inflado y fijado al ciclo de vida del `Activity` que es el elemento padre o creador.

En tu `Fragment` tienes un metodo `onCreateView` que es quien creara la vista o layout que se cargara en dicho `Fragment` contenedor, por lo tanto debes buscar la referencia en el `root` que carga. En tu código debes modificarlo de la siguiente manera:

En vez de retornar la vista inflada directamente:

```
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news, container, false);
```

Debes almacenarla en una variable y buscar las referencias en ella, por ejemplo:

*. . . Al inicio del metodo onCreateView debes hacer . . .*

```
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news, container, false);
```

Buscas las referencias en `root` de los elementos del `axml` inflado, en este caso el layout `fragment_news`.

En vez de:

```
listadoTitulos = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.vtTitulares);
```

Cambiarlo a:

```
listadoTitulos = (ListView) root.findViewById(R.id.vtTitulares);
```

y al final de todo, debes retornar `root`:

```
return root;
```

**Sugerencia:** En el `onCreateView`, siempre trata de manejar todas las tareas que pertenezcan a la creación de la vista, asignar y cambiar sus propiedades, llamar metodos que carguen los datos antes de crear la vista, etc... Esto hara que tu codigo se vea mas ordenado. Por ejemplo, en tu código:

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy permiso = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(permiso);
```

Deberías sobrescribir el método `onCreate` y ponerlo ahí. Puedes ver que metodo se llama, desde su creación hasta que el mismo es destruido en la siguiente imagen.

### Ciclo de vida de un Fragment

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Magnífica explicación, gracias por tu ayuda, supongo que tendré que leer más acerca de trabajar con fragments, pero debes perdonarme ya que soy un simple aficionado, agradecería alguna recomendación sobre algún libro para poder seguir ampliando conocimientos.

Comment: @Ciberdrac no pasa nada, todos pasamos por ahí. Puedes ampliar mas sobre los Fragments en la web, como por ejemplo [Esta documentación de Tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_fragments.htm) solo que siempre que vayas a buscar documentación sobre un método especifico, siempre dirígete a la documentacion oficial de Android, ya que siempre estan en constante actualización. De todas formas recuerda que todo se aprende con la práctica, buena suerte. Tambien [Puedes ver documentacion y ejemplos aqui](https://guides.codepath.com/android/creating-and-using-fragments)